# Cannot find name 'BigInt64Array'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2020' or later

Tags: angular, typescript, build

I have already added all the necessary components and dependencies but when I build the project I get this error projects/fs-lib/node_modules/type-fest/source/typed-array.d.ts:16:4 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'BigInt64Array'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2020' or later.
I can't remove this error since yesterday. I lose hope if someone can help me.
I'm trying to create an angular library from a finished project. I have already created a lib and copy and export all the components needed for this. The problem is that I build the lib I still receive this error since yesterday.
I use es2021, I have already reinstalled my dependencies. The project uses Angular 12.2.8 and node version 14.20.1
I am using typescript version 4.3.5.
Here is my **global project tsconfig file**:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "paths": {
      "fslib": [
        "dist/fslib/fslib",
        "dist/fslib"
      ]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2021",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
  }
}
```

**tsconfig of lib**

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/lib/interfaces/interfaces"
      ]
}
```

**my project package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "file-system",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build-library": "ng build fs-lib"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^13.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "yup": "^1.1.1",
    "yup-locales": "^1.2.12",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.7.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.38",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "~1.6.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^12.1.1",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

**package.json from the lib**:

```
{
  "name": "fs-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/localize": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/material": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.17",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~10.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "~2.11.6",
    "ajv": "~6.9.1",
    "bootstrap": "~4.5.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "13.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "~14.2.1",
    "tslib": "~2.3.0",
    "yup": "~1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "ng-circle-progress": "~1.6.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Thanks.

I tried to modify my lib and install the dependencies which should have removed the error but no

Answer (score 2):

Add `"es2020"` in the `lib` section of your tsconfig :

```
"lib": [
  "es2020",
  "es2021",
  "dom"
],
```

Comment: I have already tried it does not work.